# How to get exclusive read lock in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Node file is accessing the running balance based on last record of user's account sorted by timestamp but multiple threads in mongodb is accessing the same record at the same time so every mongo thread is getting inconsistent running balance.

Is there any way to execute the read operations sequentially ?

Comment: What do you mean? It sounds like you possibly need a tailable cursor, but you are not actually using one. Explain the purpose and desired behavior along with the current implementation and what you are getting. If all you are doing is effectively a `.sort().limit(1)` then naturally that would be expected to change with every request. Depending on frequency of new insertions of course.

Comment: @NeilLunn Here is the snippet of query :-                                                                                                                
  const matchQuery = {};
  matchQuery.client = { $in: toObjectId(context.clientAccessIds) };
  matchQuery.account = { $in: toObjectId(_accountIds) };
  return this.Model.aggregate([
    { $match: matchQuery },
    { $sort: { created_at: 1 } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$account',
        balance: { $last: '$running_balance' },
      },
    },
  ]);

Comment: @NeilLunn My general ledger collection stores the running balance field which is being populated by subtracting or adding the amount from the running balance of previous record based on debit or credit type.Now if the two threads of mongo db try to fetch the running balance at the same time then it results in dirty read so I want to have exclusive read lock while reading the running balance.